# How Can I Do Real Time Video Transmission With NDK on Android

Tags: android, c, sockets, android-ndk, video-streaming

First of all, we don't know why we are using NDK but java hasn't got a library that helping to do media stuff. We are confused about using socket on java side or c/c++ side. We are planning to use socket on java and do media stuff on c/c++ but we don't know it's possible or not.

We are waiting your suggestions.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have used adroid phones to watch streaming TV and films, so it is possible to do media stuff, yes.

Comment: What version of Android are you targeting?  Android 4.1 (API 16) added `MediaCodec`, which is available to code written in Java.  If that doesn't do what you need, then you need to to be more specific about what "media stuff" is.  What have you tried so far?

Comment: I'm targeting 2.3.3 and higher. I want to build p2p video communication application between android, iOS and windows phone. So i have to find a solution that solves the platform differences.